# Strange execution times of count()

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, performance, python-internals

The code:

```
from timeit import Timer
print(min(Timer('y=x.count(1)',setup='x=[1] * 1000').repeat(number=1000000))) 
print(min(Timer('y=x.count(0)',setup='x=[1] * 1000').repeat(number=1000000)))
```

The results on my machine:

```
0.7033228789223358
10.16116041096393
```

Can anyone explain **why** the first case is so much faster than the second? I have expected both times to be similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to the way you built your list object:

```
x = [1] * 1000
```

This creates a list with just one object, referenced 1000 times; list multiplication doesn't create copies of the value. To understand why this matters, we need to look at how Python lists do the counting.

The `list.count()` loop could be seen like this, a quick Python translation of the implementation [written in C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a755410e054e1e2390de5830befc08fe80706c66/Objects/listobject.c#L2571-L2598):

```
def count(self, value):
    count = 0
    for elem in self:
        if elem == value:
            count += 1
    return count
```

That's simple enough, right? However, it's not quite like that; the actual code uses `PyObject_RichCompareBool()`, which [**first tests for object identity**](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a755410e054e1e2390de5830befc08fe80706c66/Objects/object.c#L787-L794). It's really:

```
if elem is value or elem == value:
```

Identity testing (a simple pointer equality test) is a lot faster when *all your list elements are the same object*:

```
>>> import random
>>> v = random.randint(1000, 100000000)
>>> x = [v] * 1000
>>> all(value is v for value in x)
True
```

You can reproduce this with any random value:

```
>>> from timeit import Timer
min(Timer('y=x.count(v)',setup='import random; v = random.randint(1000, 10000000); x=[v] * 1000').repeat(number=100000))
0.2716284029884264
>>> min(Timer('y=x.count(w)',setup='import random; v = random.randint(1000, 10000000); x=[v] * 1000; w = v + 1').repeat(number=100000))
1.0827720829984173
```

A simply pointer comparison before testing for value equality is good sense, as these numbers show. And this is precisely why the Python implementation interns certain often reused values, like small integers ([those between -5 and 256, inclusive](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong)), or string values that are also valid Python identifiers.

It wouldn't have worked if you hadn't used a small integer here as the argument to `x.count()`; it is *because* `1` interned that `x.count(1)` is using an object that also is a member of the list; `x[0] is 1` is true.

Comment: My Python 3.6.9 disagrees here - `512 is 512` returns True, so does `1e23 is 1e23` and `"a" is "a"` (but strangely `(1,) is (1,)` returns False)

Comment: @Błotosmętek: *Single expression value constants are interned*.

Comment: @Błotosmętek: Separate scopes do not get to re-use constants, so `v = (lambda: 512)(); v is 512` is `False`. Look at `import dis; dis.dis('512 is 512')` to see why that will always return `True`. There are many, many areas where Python can re-use the same object and the implementation happily does so.

Comment: @Błotosmętek: also, at least in 3.7 and 3.8, `(1,) is (1,)` returns true as well, because `(1,)` is just another constant value stored with the compiled bytecode. It is False in 3.6 and older because in 3.7 the peephole constant folding responsibility was shifted to the AST optimiser, which is much smarter.